# Why is this set containment check failing?

Tags: java, equals, hashset, effective-java

I am going through the Effective Java 3rd edition and I was reading Item 10: Follow Equals contract when overriding.

There is an example there which I was trying to simulate on my machine. Below is the code for the same.

```
public class Point {
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (!(obj instanceof Point))
            return false;

        Point p = (Point)obj;
        return (x == p.x) && (y ==p.y);
    }

    // Use this for demonstration with AtomicPoint class.
    /*@Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(obj == null  || (obj.getClass() != getClass())) {
            return false;
        }

        Point p = (Point)obj;

        return p.x == x && p.y == y;
    }*/
}

public class AtomicPoint extends Point{
    private static final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();

    public AtomicPoint(int x, int y) {
        super(x, y);
        counter.incrementAndGet();
    }

    public static int getCounter() {
        return counter.get();
    }

    private static Set<Point> sampleSet = new HashSet<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        sampleSet.add(new Point(1,2));
        sampleSet.add(new Point(1,3));
        sampleSet.add(new Point(1,4));

        AtomicPoint ap = new AtomicPoint(1,3);

        // This should return true but its returning false
        System.out.println(sampleSet.contains(ap));
    }
}
```

As you can see from the comment in the AtomicPoint class, I am getting false for the contains check, whereas Joshua Bloch states that this should return true. Can someone help me here?

Comment: You are missing Item 11: "Always override hashCode when you override equals" - overriding equals alone is not sufficient!

Comment: Thanks and yes, I hadnt gotten that far in the book yet. And also thought the examples in the book relied on the concepts explained in a given item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For using `HashSet<T>` or `HashMap<T>` you need to override `hashCode()` methods from super class. You should have in your editor automatically generating `hashCode()` and `equals()` methods (and i'm suggesting you to use that always in every class). If you want to use `TreeSet<T>` or `TreeMap<T>` you will need to implement `Comparable` or `Comparator<T>` interface and override their `compare()` or `compareTo()` methods for using it.